# JMeter understand Thread Group / Throughput and INCLUDE

Tags: jmeter

1. I have a few question to clarify on my understanding of how JMeter works.

a. Thread Group determine the number of users but it does not determine how many HTML requests are generated per sec ?  By default, I notice that every user will send a HTML request at a rate of 2 RPS.

b. If I want to change the RPS per user, then I need to use the Through Put Timer.  But the Timer can only lower the request rate from 2 RPS to a lower number.  It does not increase the RPS.

c. In order to increase the RPS, I need to add more Threads.

d. Does this mean we are limited to 2 RPS per user ?  I see some website have links to many other websites so a webpage refresh would make many requests.

Is this the way JMeter works ?

2. I have a load test which has 8 transaction (eg CRUD,...).  I intend to create a overall Test Plan and I want to use INCLUDE to add all the 8 txn.  Do I just record the website and INCLUDE ?  What should I include, only the HTML requests ?
3. I'm also thinking of adding Think Time and Add Variables in the 8 scripts before I INCLUDE.
4. Do I add the Config Element (eg CSV Dataset Config) in the 8 scripts or the overall Test Plan ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. By default each JMeter thread (virtual user) executes requests as fast as it can. If you want to slow JMeter down to mimic a real user which doesn't hammer the server non-stop and needs some time to "think" between operations - use [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers). More information: [How do I Correlate the Number of (Concurrent) Users with Hits Per Second](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420695-How-do-I-Correlate-the-Number-of-Concurrent-Users-with-Hits-Per-Second)

   If you want more RPS - add more threads (assuming that the system under test can give you more RPS)
2. You should INCLUDE everything which is related to **your** website (images, scripts, styles, fonts, sounds, etc.) but in the same manner as your browser does, i.e. don't record these requests and instead configure JMeter to download embedded resources and use [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) so JMeter would request these resources just like browser does. Any requests to "external" websites should be excluded (unless they're also developed and supported and in scope for testing)
3. That's a good approach, if you use a value more than once it makes sense to declare it via [User Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) so you would be able to amend the value only in one place
4. You add it according to your scenarios, be informed about [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I don't understand the part about "(images, scripts, styles, fonts, sounds, etc.)".  These are in the response which won't be INCLUDED, right ?  So my include scripts will consist of HTTP Request (with Variables), Timers, and may be Assertions as well.  I believe the INCLUDE will just add it in as if they are part of the overall Test Plan ?

Comment: I'm thinking that in my overall Test Plan, I will add all the a). Config Elements, b) a Thread Group (probably Ultimate), c) a Constant Throughput Timer (to limit the overall transaction rate), then d) 8 ThroughPut Controllers, and then INCLUDE the scripts in respective controllers, e) Listeners